# Read 2 lines of input into 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, delphi, input, stdin, pascal

Im trying to convert an input like the following:

```
1 5 9 12 16 21 25
3 7 12 13 14 15 16 19 20 26
```

Into 2 arrays, one array for each line of input. Currently I have the following code:

```
FUNCTION readId : integer;

    VAR
        id : integer;
        i : integer;
        first : a;
        second : a;

    TYPE
        a = ARRAY[0..(size - 1)] OF integer;

    BEGIN

        i := 0;
        WHILE (NOT eoln) DO BEGIN
            read(id);
            first[i] := id;
            Inc(i);
        END;


        i := 0;
        WHILE ((NOT eof) AND (NOT eoln)) DO BEGIN
            read(id);
            second[i] := id;
            Inc(i);
        END;
    END;
```

This works for the first array, but the second array isn't filled. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the debugger to find out why.  Consider the possibility that reading does not proceed to the second line.

Comment: Why are you using old style Pascal I/O, instead of newer RTL style I/O?  You can use a `TStringList` or `TStreamReader` to read the individual lines, and a separate `TStringList` to parse each line.

Comment: Btw, as written, your code will not compile because the declaration of `a` comes before the `type` declaration which defines it, and `size` is not defined.  In future please include your `actual` code so readers do not have to waste their time on errors like those.

Comment: @MartynA I can't find how to debug my pascal code?

Comment: Where have you looked?  See e.g. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Debugging_the_Application_(IDE_Tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

The first `while` loop will end when `eoln` is `true`, and at the beginning of the second `while` loop `eoln` is still `true`. This means that the body of the second `while` loop is never executed, because the condition, `((not eof)) and (not(eoln))`, will be `false`.

You can try putting a `readln` before the second `while` loop.